# Workflow logic for multiple-approval process

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, infopath

I have the need to create a workflow that will begin when a user submits an infopath form to a document library.  Some fields will be extracted from this form to build the workflow.

Steps:

1. Notify the form submitter's manager and request that they approve or disapprove.
2. One or more other users will be notified and requested to approve or disapprove the submitted form.  If any of them reject the form, the original requester should be notified and requested to re-submit the form.

I can make a workflow for step 1 and then check the value of that field in the task to see if it's either approved or disapproved before moving onto the next step or not.

The issue I'm having is how to check whether someone has rejected or approved in the 2nd step, since there could be multiple users.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After step 1, you can track the workflow in the "workflow Tasks" list, i.e., you can get who rejected it, when they did it and why they did it(if you have a notes/reason column).

If you/your company can afford to buy a third party tool like nintex/bamboo workflow conductor/k2, this approval process come out of the box. They are a bit expensive though